# Sorting, iterating and 'unsorting' a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm working with spatial matrix data arranged in a python list of lists. I want to run a number of calculations on each cell in the dataset in descending order using Numpy. To accomplish this I wrote the following function (the x + 1 calculation for each cell is just placeholder):

```
def calcHydrology(m):

    hydrology = np.array(c.deepcopy(m))

    for x in np.nditer(np.sort(hydrology), op_flags=['readwrite']):
        x[...] = x + 1

    ???

    return hydrology.tolist()
```

m is the matrix in the form of regular nested python lists (with a 150,100 shape). '???' is where I need to get the modified values back in the original order.

So in particular I'd like to know how to 'unsort' a modified, sorted numpy array, and in general I'm open to overall better approaches to the problem of sorting, iterating and 'unsorting' numpy arrays.

Comment: Why don't you just use a list in this situation? You don't seem to be using `numpy` for it's fast, vector calculations, so this is *probably slower* than using a list, especially if you are assigning, etc.

Comment: Also, `deepcopy` is not necessary if you are going to pass it to `np.array` (unless your array is `dtype=object`, but then why would you be using an array at all?)

Comment: But anyway, have you tried using `argsort` which returns *sorted indices* which you could iterate over, so the actual array never changes order?

Comment: But again I must stress, if you are going to not use vectorized operations, especially with an array that small, an equivalent list-based implementation will be much faster. And probably easier to write.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for all the input. Would storing the data as dicts with the spatial data coordinates as keyed attributes be a dumb approach performancewise? Then I could just forget about the shape of the list and use the stored XY data in the dicts, which might be a bit more readable.

Comment: I couldn't say without more details about what you are doing exactly. It's a little vague